# SAML Global Logout

Tags: saml, adfs, spring-security-saml2

I have setup two **SPs(service provider)** with **ADFS server**.
Currently I can logout well in each SP. However I would like to implement that once the IdP receives logout request, it will invalidate the login session from all the SPs.

Could it be achieve?

NOTE : I am implementing with SAML 2.0 and ADFS(3.0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.